# How will deduct the input data when deleting created new input javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a calculating table that will compute all the inputted data,

there will be times that user can input multi data by clicking/adding new input tab.

the Tax area is where TAX will be input, it will subtract to the total debit to get the Service with no TAX.

but my problem is when clicking the "del" button the value that has been inputted does not subtract from the total value.

```js
jQuery($ => {init_input();}); 

function init_input()
{

//SUB DEBIT
$(document).on("input paste", ".expenses_debit", function() {
    var sum1 = 0;
     
    $(".expenses_debit").each(function(){
        sum1 += +$(this).val();
    });
   
    $("#sub_debit").val(sum1);
});

//Operating Expenses
$(document).on("input paste", ".total_bir", function() {
   var sum3 = 0;
    $(".total_bir").each(function(){
        sum3 += +$(this).val();
    });
      var qq = $("#sub_debit").val();
      const towtal = qq-sum3;
    $("#new_operating_credit").val(towtal);    
});

//Sub Credit
$(document).on("input paste", ".expenses_credit", function() {
   var sum2 = 0;
    $(".expenses_credit").each(function(){
        sum2 += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#sub_credit").val(sum2);    
});

}

//expendable furniture
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper       = $(".input_fields_wrap27"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button27"); //Add button ID
  
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<tr style="background:silver"><td><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#" class="remove_field27"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-light">del</button></a></div><td>Service2</td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]"></div></td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="0.00" disabled></div></td></tr>'); //add input box
    }

     init_input();
  });
  
  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field27", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest("tr").remove(); x--;
  })
  });

//bir
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper       = $(".input_fields_wrap28"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button28"); //Add button ID
  
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<tr style="background:silver"><td><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#" class="remove_field28"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-light">del</button></a></div><td>Tax</td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0.00" disabled></div></td><td><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span><input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_credit total_bir" placeholder="0.00" id="bir_credit[]"></div></td><td></td></tr>');
    }
    init_input();
  });
  
  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field28", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest("tr").remove(); x--;

  })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-fixed" align="center" style="font-size: 9pt">
    <thead style="font-size: 11pt">
      <tr align="center">
        <th width="15%">Check Series</th>
        <th>UACS Object Code</th>
        <th width="20%">Debit Amount</th>
        <th width="20%">Credit Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="input_fields_wrap26">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light add_field_button26">add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Service1</td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
    <tbody class="input_fields_wrap27">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light add_field_button27">add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Service2</td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_debit operating_debit total1" placeholder="0.00" id="expendable_furniture_debit[]">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm " placeholder="0.00" disabled>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tbody class="input_fields_wrap28">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light add_field_button28">add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Tax</td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" name="bir_debit" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0.00" disabled>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
              <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
              <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" name="new_bir_credit" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_credit total_bir" placeholder="0.00" id="bir_credit" required="">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Service with no TAX</td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0.00" id="new_operating_debit total1" disabled>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 9pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm expenses_credit" placeholder="0.00" disabled id="new_operating_credit">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h5 align="right"><b>SUB TOTAL</b></h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" id="sub_debit">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: 16pt">P</span>
            <input type="text" style="font-size:12px" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" id="sub_credit">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your code is still VERY non-dry. Just calculate EVERYTHING on EVERY change.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).